# How to remove existing labels and add time scale labels to x axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
Date        B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9 B10 B11 B12 B13  B14
10/03/2015  NA 1.8  NA 2.7 1.1 4.4 2.0 0.2 2.1 0.8 1.4 0.6 1.4  1.8
17/03/2015  NA  NA 2.8 0.7 1.7 3.5 2.0 0.3 2.0 1.2 1.0 0.8 1.7  1.0
```

(+ 26 more dates)

I just want to plot the first three columns (B1-B3) so I did this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mydata<-read.csv("toc.csv",header=T)
df <- data.frame(mydata$Date, mydata$B1, mydata$B2, mydata$B3)
ggplot(df, aes(mydata$Date, y=value, colour = "red")) +
geom_point(aes(y = mydata$B1, col = "B1")) + 
geom_point(aes(y = mydata$B2, col = "B2")) +
geom_point(aes(y = mydata$B3, col = "B3")) +
labs(title ="Total organic carbon in the Barlwyd 
        upstream sites B1-B3, 2015.", x = "Date",
y = "Total organic carbon (mg/L).")
```

The result gives a graph with a cluttered x axis with every date sampled put on the x axis. How do I go about tidying up the x axis so labels appear as a monthly interval? My data is taken roughly on a weekly basis.

Thanks in advance!
Still learning the ropes!
;-)

Comment: First, come up with a reproducible example or share a subset of your data. Second you can just `melt` the data frame and colour them. No need to use to `geom_point` so many times. Read ggplot tutorials

Comment: Can't reproduce your example, but by adding `scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 month")` should help you.

Comment: ...also while you're learning ggplot, **never** use `$` when mapping variables inside `aes()`. For instance, `y = mydata$B1` should be `y = B1` and there should be a column called `B1` in the data frame `df`.

Comment: Thanks all thats great! Jimbou's suggestion worked great.